# OpenCV C++ 3 Dimensional Mat Data Access Wrong Values

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I am using C++ OpenCV DNN to get results into a Mat. Here, `dnnResult` is the output Mat. The output values are float. I want extract `66` values into `3` separate arrays or a `3 x 66` matrix.

```
dnnResult.size[0] = 3
dnnResult.size[1] = 1
dnnResult.size[2] = 66
dnnResult.dims = 3
```

I tried looping like this to get value, but the results are wrong. There is no error for accessing out of bound data from 3d Mat.

```
for(int m = 0; m < 3; m++){
    for(int n = 0; n < 66; n++){
        myNetOutput2d[m][n] = dnnResult.at<double>(m, 0, n);    
    }
}
```

I also tried following [How to access a 3 dimensional Matrix elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44224893/how-to-access-a-3-dimensional-matrix-elements),

```
typedef Vec<double, 66> Vec66d;
for(int m = 0; m < 3; m++){
    for(int n = 0; n < 66; n++){
        Vec66d tmp_vec66d = dnnResult.at<double>(0, m);
        myNetOutput2d[m][n] = tmp_vec66d.val[n];

    }
}
```

I am trying to get python equivalent of assigning values of size `66` into 3 separate arrays,

```
arr1, arr2, arr3 = dnnResult
```

Comment: Why are you accessing data as `double` if result is `float`?

Comment: Why should assigning value to a wider type be a problem? I am worried if  `dnnResult.at<double>(m, 0, n);` part of accessing Mat data is correct or not. I tried with `dnnResult.at<double>(100, 100, 100);` which gives value without getting any out of bound error. The reason for my doubt, https://joebartelmo.com/computer_vision/opencv-accessors/.

Comment: it's not getting type as wide cast. what `<double>` does is casting data as `double *` and accessing its data with index. the index is not out of bounds, but the actual pointer is out of bound. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will check your answer by next week. If that works I will accept your answer.

Comment: I rechecked the returned data type in python which is `np.float32` as C++ `float`. Seems to be partially working now. The trained model itself also seems partially responsible for bad results as it was trained on a very small dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change
`dnnResult.at<double>(..)` to `dnnResult.at<float>(..)`

+ more information about `cv::Mat::at`

```
template<typename _Tp> inline
_Tp& Mat::at(int i0, int i1, int i2)
{
    CV_DbgAssert( elemSize() == sizeof(_Tp) );
    return *(_Tp*)ptr(i0, i1, i2);
}

inline
const uchar* Mat::ptr(int i0, int i1, int i2) const
{
    CV_DbgAssert(dims >= 3);
    CV_DbgAssert(data);
    CV_DbgAssert((unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0]);
    CV_DbgAssert((unsigned)i1 < (unsigned)size.p[1]);
    CV_DbgAssert((unsigned)i2 < (unsigned)size.p[2]);
    return data + i0 * step.p[0] + i1 * step.p[1] + i2 * step.p[2];
}
```

`cv::Mat` holds data with a raw pointer, and `cv::Mat::at<_Tp>` access its data with casting a pointer to `_Tp*`. The index is not out of bound, but the actual data is got from out bounds because `double` is `64 bit`, while the `float` is `32 bit` in OpenCV.

### So, you have to **know** you're `cv::Mat`'s correct type when accessing to it.

If you want to cast the data do `double`, you have to cast after getting the correct data.

```
myNetOutput2d[m][n] = (double)dnnResult.at<float>(m, 0, n);
```

or, convert the `dnnResult`'s type to `double` before accessing to it.

```
dnnResult.convertTo(dnnResult, CV_64F); 
...
myNetOutput2d[m][n] = dnnResult.at<double>(m, 0, n);
```